# OWASP implementation in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owasp

I'm task to implement OWASP standard on my mvc projects. I've found documentation [here](https://www.owasp.org/images/6/67/OWASPApplicationSecurityVerificationStandard3.0.pdf) also we have .Net space [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_.NET_Project) .

My problem is that i don't understand couple of points and there is no online support (even in glossary section) for this (or i haven't found one)for example : point 1.9 Verify the application has a clear separation between the data layer, controller layer and the display layer, such that security decisions can be enforced on trusted systems. I'm working on MVC application so there is a separation between layers but what "security decisions" word mean in this context i don't understand - ?

Any help or point to the right directions in appreciated

**Update : 2016-01-11**
Also what this sentence means 10.13 - Ensure forward secrecy ciphers are in use to mitigate passive attackers recording traffic in context of mvc app.

**Update : 2016-01-12**
Another Problem : 19.4 Verify application deployments are adequately sandboxed, containerized orisolated to delay and deter attackers from attacking other applications. ?

Comment: What is meant is that you should not sprinkle your code with statements like `if (User == RecordOwner)`, but fix that in a centralized place.

Comment: could you explain it a bit ? currently i get data from one user service in all applications and this service allow user to see only data relevant to him so we can assume that i've pass this point ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that 10.13 relating to Forward Secrecy is probably referring to enabling *SSL Forward Secrecy* for your site, something like [this](https://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12).

This helps prevent an attacker from potentially using brute force decryption techniques that might be possible if they can capture large volumes of your  traffic.

Comment: do you know where can i find some "human" explanation of some OWASP  standard points  ?